# I wonder why my proxy object is null.. (jpa, hibernate, kotlin)

Tags: hibernate, kotlin, proxy, spring-data-jpa, lazy-loading

```kotlin
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = [CascadeType.ALL], mappedBy = "wsi")
var records: MutableList<RecordEntity>? = null
```

there is a code of wsi entity.

and i did a test and the test flow is like this

```kotlin
@Test
fun findLatestByWsiIdTest() {

    val em = entityManager.createEntityManager()
    val tx = em.transaction
    tx.begin()
    createDummyData() //inserting a data for test

    em.flush()
    em.clear()
    val allProjectIdList = projectRepository.findAll().map { it.id!! }

    em.clear()


    println("*********************  start  ***************************")
    allProjectIdList.forEach { id ->
        run {
            val wsiList = wsiRepository.findAllByProjectId(id) //.map { it.id!! }
            println("each wsis of project size : ${wsiList.size}")

            wsiList.forEach { wsi ->
                run {
                    println(wsi.records?.size) // every records field are null..
                }
            }
        }
    }
    println("*********************  end  ***************************")
    tx.rollback()
}
```

i dont know why the records field is null not a proxy object whenever i query for wsiList

any help...?

---

i fixed this error.

when i test repository.

1. use only autowired EntityManager
2. put @Transactional annotation on the method

keeping these two things up

Comment: no need to ask any Help?

Comment: Specify the problem.. any welcome to stack overflow